# sms IPhone html link not working

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ios, jqtouch

Note this is for mobile site is using jqtjs http://jqtjs.com/

I have tested the following on two different IPhone 4 models 1 running 6.1.3(updated) and  5.1.1(old jailbroken)

I tested using both Safari(up to date) and Chrome (up to date)

I used various methods:

```
 sms:
 smsto:
 sms://
```

The following work here on the fiddle page when put on my mobile site im trying to get working I get nothing.

works: http://jsfiddle.net/gSPEe/
not working :http://redwirelogic.com/help/ (sorry for the page link but idk how else to describe this)

```
<a href="sms:">test1</a><br>
<a href="sms:5555555555:">test2</a><br>
<a href="sms:555-555-5555">test3</a><br>

<a href="smsto:">test4</a><br>
<a href="smsto:5555555555:">test5</a><br>
<a href="smsto:555-555-5555:">test6</a><br>

<a href="sms://">test7</a><br>
<a href="sms://5555555555">test8</a><br>
<a href="sms://555-555-5555">test9</a><br>
```

Nothing is working! Id love some help figuring this out.

To test if something was wrong i confirmed that the tel and mailto work for calling and email.

I found the link below and well yea so it is documented to work right?

[Ios development library-Text Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html)

Comment: note it does work on the jfiddle page not on my website though :-/ never experienced problem like this...The link acts like it points to no where href=''

Comment: any suggestions before I start digging through there code?

Comment: i dropped the extra stuff lol ----nope nothing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33593/discussion-between-chris-truman-and-tman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Jquery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/).  JQTouch is basically abandonware and is no longer maintained.  Can't find any way to stop it from disabling sms: links.